# Passing local variable as a global

Tags: javascript

I am drawing a line using Google Maps V3, and I want to be able to pass a local variable `loc` as global, so I can use it outside of this entire code. How can I do this?

```
if(this.flightdetails.route_details.length > 0)
{
    $.each(this.flightdetails.posreports, function(i, nav)
    {
        var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(nav.latitude, nav.longitude);
        // Rest of code

        path[path.length] = loc;
        focus_bounds.extend(loc);
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't make it a local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var loc;
if(this.flightdetails.route_details.length > 0)
{
    $.each(this.flightdetails.posreports, function(i, nav)
    {
        loc = new google.maps.LatLng(nav.latitude, nav.longitude);
        // Rest of code

        path[path.length] = loc;
        focus_bounds.extend(loc);
    });
}
console.log(loc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your variable global:

```
var loc; // global
if(this.flightdetails.route_details.length > 0)
{
    $.each(this.flightdetails.posreports, function(i, nav)
    {
        loc = new google.maps.LatLng(nav.latitude, nav.longitude); // with no var
        // Rest of code

        path[path.length] = loc;
        focus_bounds.extend(loc);
    });
}
```